# Dragstart event does not fire in firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a problem with a `dragstart` event in my JavaScript. When using Chrome it works perfectly fine, but not in Firefox, where it wont fire at all.

```
(function () {
        var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone-add');
        var dropzone2 = document.getElementById('dropzone-del');
        var draggedItem;
        function drag (e) { //This one does not fire in firefox.. I have tried many methods..
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.src);
            draggedItem = e.target; 
        }
        var displayUploads = function (data) {
            var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads');

            for(index=0; index<data.length; index=index+1){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                var image = document.createElement('img');
                div.className = 'col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb';
                anchor.className = 'thumbnail';
                anchor.href = '#';
                image.className = 'img-responsive';
                image.src = data[index].file;
                image.alt = data[index].name;
                anchor.appendChild(image);
                div.appendChild(anchor);
                uploads.insertBefore(div, uploads.firstChild);
                image.setAttribute('draggable', true);
                image.ondragstart = function(event) {drag(event)}; //This is the elment that will be draggable.
                //image.addEventListener('dragstart', drag, false);

            }
        }
        var upload = function (files) {
            var formData = new FormData(), 
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            index;
            for(index=0; index<files.length; index = index+1){
                formData.append('file[]', files[index]);
            }
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                displayUploads(data);
            }
            xhr.open('post', 'upload.php');
            xhr.send(formData);


        }
        var removeFile = function(src){
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var data = this.responseText;
                console.log(data);
            }
            xhr.open('post', 'delete.php');
            xhr.send(src);
        }

        dropzone.ondrop = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.className = 'dropzone';
            if(e.dataTransfer.files.length < 1){
                alert('Use the other dropzone to delete.');
                return false;
            }
            else
                upload(e.dataTransfer.files);
        }
        dropzone.ondragover = function () {
            this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
            return false;
        }
        dropzone.ondragleave = function () {
            this.className = 'dropzone';
            return false;
        }
        dropzone2.ondrop = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.className = 'dropzone';
            var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
            console.log(draggedItem);
            console.log(data);
            //removeFile(data);
        }
        dropzone2.ondragover = function () {
            this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
            return false;
        }

    }());
```

The images output becomes properly draggable and is working fine in Chrome. I have tried to use methods like `event.originalEvent` without success. Would appreciate any help, I am stuck right now. Please ignore the awfulness in the loop.

## On top html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Upload - drag drop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="content-fluid">
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone-add">Drag the file you want to upload here</div>
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone-del">Drag the file you want to delete here</div>
    
    <div class="row" id="uploads">
            
    </div>
</div>
```

## Upload.php

```
<?php 
$uploaded = array();
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
    $upload_folder = 'uploads/';
    
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position => $name){
        $upload_path = $upload_folder . time() . '_' . basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$position]);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position], $upload_path)){
            $uploaded[] = array('name' => $name, 'file' => $upload_path);
        }

    }
    echo json_encode($uploaded);
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you try this: var element = e.originalEvent.target;

Comment: Where would I put that? The function drag will not be fired at all. If you mean inside drag, I have tried that.

Comment: Have you tried switching from an inline event to registering an event listener with `addEventListener`? Do any of your inline events fire?

Comment: How can I test it? If I put this code on my page will it work?

Comment: You will need the html above. I used addEventListener the way that it is outcommented atm. It did not register anything. The other methods works fine though (dropping a file) in the other dropzone.

Comment: I do not see HTML - all is JavaScript

Comment: Actually there will be hard to test it. I am new to this forum and dont know much about the features. The thing is, I have a server side php, which uploads the files dragged and returns the url. I will edit the thread.

Comment: By more testing, it turns out that the problem is "image". When I bind an inline event as suggested to the div - it works.. I rather using the image still though..

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Firefox.. Here's a simple test case: https://jsfiddle.net/9s7fks12/2/